# How do I make my cards self-contained while making the code scalable if I needed to add more cards?

Tags: javascript

https://lolticus.github.io/duplicate-Article-Card-Component/ <= Github Website

https://github.com/lolticus/duplicate-Article-Card-Component <= Github Respository

So this is a challenge from Frontend Mentor to create a card that can display social links depending on your view port size. If it's a lone standing card, the code works just fine. But I realized when duplicating the card, the share-button itself when toggled would display the social links on both cards and I don't really know how to make the cards self-contained from one another. I'm sorry if my description is confusing as I can't seem to find a solution online. I want to make it so that whenever I duplicate the card, it works as intended.

here's my Javascript code:

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.share-button');
var tooltip = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip'); 

button.forEach(btn => { 
    btn.addEventListener("click", e => { 

        btn.classList.toggle("active")

        tooltip.forEach((tt) => {

            tt.classList.toggle("expand")


        })

    })

})
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your issue is that you expand all the tooltips when the user clicks that button. What you need to do is to expand only the tooltip associated with that button. So from what I can see from your code, you need to get the parent container and get the tooltip of that component:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.share-button');

buttons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", e => { 
        btn.classList.toggle("active");
        const assossiatedTootip = btn.parentNode.querySelector('.tooltip')
        assossiatedTootip.classList.toggle("expand")
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've just started learning Javascript and I couldn't for the life of me, understand how I would do this. Thank you truly!

Comment: Hello Again Mr Thanos, I was wondering if you had any recommendation for a beginner like me to start learning Javascript? Once again, thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello Kam, I am glad to see that you are interested in learning Javascript.
Well, I suggest looking at the info section https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info, which has a lot of useful links to help you learn Javascript.

Comment: Cool! I'll look into it. Thanks!